# Creating an anchor with attribute called offset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a very strange behavior when dynamically creating an  anchor with the following code:

```
var newAnchor = $('<a>', {
                    'href': '#',
                    'class': 'seeMoreFromSection load-multi',
                    'offset':'12',
                    'type': '15',
                    'sec': '4'
                }).html('See more');

$('a.seeMoreFromSection').replaceWith(newAnchor);
```

The problem is in the attribute that is called `offset`, it's resulting in the following error: `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'using' in 12`. When I remove the line `'offset':'12'` everything works fine.
I made it work by adding this attribute after creating the anchor:

```
$('a.seeMoreFromSection').attr('offset', '12');
```

But I still don't understand what is the problem, is it some sort of a reserved word or something?

UPDATE: the browser Google Chrome 33.0.1750.154 m

Comment: yea it is. offset in jQuery is the element's absolute position from 0,0 of the window. although im not sure if it would cause this problem

Comment: That's one reason you shouldn't use invalid attributes on DOM node, use `data-*` attributes instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it can be seen in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes#creating-new-elements), you can use valid HTML attributes, valid event types and some jQuery methods (`offset()` being one of them):

> If the second argument is passed, the HTML string in the first
>   argument must represent a a simple element with no attributes. As of
>   jQuery 1.4, any event type can be passed in, and the following jQuery
>   methods can be called: `val`, `css`, `html`, `text`, `data`, `width`, `height`, or
>   `offset`.

`offset`, `type` and `sec` would not be valid HTML attributes anyways, so you cannot expect your tools to accept them. You can use `data-` attributes to make your special attributes valid, or you can use the [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method of jQuery, unless you specifically need to store data in HTML attributes (which is not the case most of the time).

Answer (score 0):

`offset` happens to also be the name of a jQuery method. By attempting to add that attribute, you're telling jQuery to set that element's offset and providing incorrect arguments.

It expects something like this and is throwing an exception:
    $('',{ offset: {top: 2, left: 4} })

You should really be using `data-` attributes to capture non-standard things like this. `data-offset` would be a nice way to represent that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the data attribute instead of creating your own.

```
var newAnchor = $('<a>', {
                'href': '#',
                'class': 'seeMoreFromSection load-multi',
                'data-offset':'12',
                'type': '15',
                'sec': '4'
            }).html('See more');

$('a.seeMoreFromSection').replaceWith(newAnchor);
```

can be accessed like this,

```
$('*[data-offset="12"]');
```

Comment: If you are already at it, you could use it for `type` and `sec` as well :).

Answer (score -2):

use capital Offset ... will solve your problem :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var newAnchor = $('<a>', {
                    'href': '#',
                    'class': 'seeMoreFromSection load-multi',
                    'Offset':'12',
                    'type': '15',
                    'sec': '4'
                }).html('See more');

$('a.seeMoreFromSection').replaceWith(newAnchor);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YZZ62/

Comment: How can you just say it is not useful! have you tried it!?

Comment: I know it is not a valid html attribute ... but what if his system requires it!

Comment: This is a hack that works now and not guaranteed to work in the next jQuery version. Also, not a good practice to invent your own HTML attributes. I downvoted because I do not suggest doing this. If his system requires it, the system should be fixed, or he should simply use `attr()`.